# WSO2 API Manager is not responding to a request that returns zip file (application/octet-stream)

Tags: api, rest, wso2

Using WSO2 API Manager 1.3.1.  Trying to use the API Manager to proxy to a REST service.  I have set up the service in API Mgr and can successfully post and get responses, typically json, though some are text.

However, when I try to GET a resource that returns binary content (a zip "file", content-type:application/octet-stream), the API Manager does not seem to respond and I can see an error in the console window (i'm running wso2server.bat in console):

> [2013-07-03 11:52:05,048]  WARN - SourceHandler Connection time out
>   while writing the response: 173.21.1.22:1268->173.21.1.22:8280

I have an HTTPModule on my internal service and it seems to be responding with the appropriate content (I can see the GET and response data logged).  I can also call to the internal service directly and get a response, so that end of things seems OK.  But going through the API Manager seems to fail.

I found information on enabling other content-types:

[WSO2 API Manager - Publishing API with non-XML response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14854157/wso2-api-manager-publishing-api-with-non-xml-response)

http://wso2.com/library/articles/binary-relay-efficient-way-pass-both-xml-non-xml-content-through-apache-synapse

Using that information I tried to enable the application/octet-stream for messageFormatter and messageBuilder using the binary relay and it did not help (or seem to make a difference).  I have even disabled all other content-types and use the binary relay for all content-types and it does not help.

Currently, I'm running with just the following in both axis2.xml and axis2_client.xml (in their appropriate sections):

```
<messageBuilder contentType=".*" class="org.wso2.carbon.relay.BinaryRelayBuilder"/
<messageFormatter contentType=".*" class="org.wso2.carbon.relay.ExpandingMessageFormatter"/>
```

I still get my json and text responses, but WSO2 times out getting the zip content.  I saw the JIRA referenced in axis2.xml about enabling the ".*" relay, but as the other requests seem to work, I'm not sure it's an issue for me.  I did try adding 
'format="rest"' to the API definition, but it seemed to break all operations even the ones that worked prior so I've pulled it back out.

Any ideas on what is happening or how to dig in and debug this will help.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After working with this for much too long, it turns out that my WSO2 configuration was correct, using the Message Relay and BinaryRelayBuilder, etc.  While my REST service could reply immediately, I was setting a HTTP header that I assume WSO2 does not like, because when i removed it WSO2 would reply at an expected rate (instantly).
I was setting the header:

> Transfer-Encoding: binary

When I removed that header from my service reply, then WSO2 operated as expected.  I don't know if that's a "bug" in WSO2 or if I was implementing incorrectly, but I do have what seems like a "workaround" by omitting that header from my service response.